# golang unmarshal using db tags

Tags: sql, postgresql, go, unmarshalling, sqlx

I have a sql query which fetches the list of cities nested inside provinces nested inside countries

```
SELECT
    C.*,
    P.provinces
FROM
    countries AS C
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        P.country_id,
        json_agg(json_build_object(
            'id', P.id,
            'name', P.name,
            'slug', P.slug,
            'cities', Ci.cities
        )) AS provinces
    FROM
        provinces AS P
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            Ci.province_id,
            json_agg(json_build_object(
                'id', Ci.id,
                'name', Ci.name,
                'slug', Ci.slug
            )) AS cities
        FROM
            cities AS Ci
        GROUP BY Ci.province_id
    ) AS Ci ON Ci.province_id = P.id
    GROUP BY P.country_id
) AS P ON P.country_id = C.id
```

I am fetching this data into slice of countries

```
type Country struct {
    Id         int64         `json:"id" db:"id"`
    ISOCode2   string        `json:"isoCode2" db:"iso_code_2"`
    ISOCode3   string        `json:"isoCode3" db:"iso_code_3"`
    ISONumCode string        `json:"isoNumCode" db:"iso_num_code"`
    Name       string        `json:"name" db:"name"`
    Slug       string        `json:"slug" db:"slug"`
    Provinces  SliceProvince `json:"provinces" db:"provinces"`
}

type SliceProvince []Province

func (provinces *SliceProvince) Scan(src any) (err error) {
    if src == nil {
        return
    }
    var source []byte
    switch src := src.(type) {
    case []byte:
        source = src
    case string:
        source = []byte(src)
    default:
        return fmt.Errorf("unsupported type in scan:%v", src)
    }
    err = json.Unmarshal(source, provinces)
    return
}

type Province struct {
    Id     int64     `json:"id" db:"id"`
    Name   string    `json:"name" db:"name"`
    Slug   string    `json:"slug" db:"slug"`
    Cities SliceCity `json:"cities" db:"cities"`
}

type SliceCity []City

func (cities *SliceCity) Scan(src any) (err error) {
    if src == nil {
        return
    }
    var source []byte
    switch src := src.(type) {
    case []byte:
        source = src
    case string:
        source = []byte(src)
    default:
        return fmt.Errorf("unsupported type in scan")
    }
    err = json.Unmarshal(source, cities)
    return
}

type City struct {
    Id   int64  `json:"id" db:"id"`
    Name string `json:"name" db:"name"`
    Slug string `json:"slug" db:"slug"`
}
```

Now, my main query is that in the scan methods for these models, I want to do unmarshalling using `db` tags instead of `json` tags. Is there any workaround which I can do for this.

I came up with a thought of unmarshalling it to a map, then change their keys from db tag ones to json tag ones, then marshal and unmarshal it to the corresponding struct. But when there would be nesting of models, or slices involved, that would increase the complexity

Comment: You can't change the tags that `json.Unmarshal` uses. But it doesn't look like you need to. The `json` and `db` tags seem to be identical for those types that implement the Scanner interface and use json unmarshaling. So what is it that you're actually trying to do that doesn't work?

Comment: Currently, for Province and City model they are same. Now, if I want to fetch a user and put its country details in json in SQL query, as you can see country model has different tags, OR if some other fields need to be added in the city model with different tags then it would create a problem

Comment: In those cases you simply need to use the correct keys *inside the SQL* when constructing the JSON with `json_build_object`.

Comment: Can use that, but the thing is: I want to focus on `db` tags while writing SQL query, or while scanning the results from db. Is there any function provided by golang which can unmarshal it using `db` tags

Comment: No, there isn't.